# How to apply --trace everywhere?

Tags: haskell-stack

Is there a way to configure stack so that everywhere it makes sense (i.e. all my code, but not the resolver packages), --trace is applied, so that I get a backtrace wherever I can?

Comment: How do you currently use `--trace` and how does its effect fall short of your expectations?

Comment: I want to *not* use it, is the point; I want it to be the default, and not have to specify it as a command line argument.

Comment: To compile with profiling options you can configure the `build` option as explained [here](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#debugging). Then configure `"*": -with-rtsopts=-xc` in [the `ghc-options` field](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#ghc-options). In principle, that should work.